# Can you dynamically allocate a class with a vector as a field in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have a vector inside a dynamically allocated object. Like so:

```
class VectorUser{
    vector<int> v;  
    //other stuff
};

//somewhere
VectorUser * vu = new VectorUser();
delete vu;
```

Is this code safe? If so, how does c++ know how much memory to allocate when the size of the vector could be anything?

Comment: code is correct. `std::vector` has fixed size (mainly 3 members : data, size, capacity (pointers (possibly integral type for the last ones))) (extra allocation is done for data).

Comment: @Jarod42 Ah so the vector object just stores a pointer for the actual data. That cleared it up. Thanks.

Comment: consider that if this would be problematic (for the reason you think) then a function `void foo(std::vector<int> x)` would be problematic as well

Comment: Generally, the binary representation of all objects of the same type has the same size (achievable by the `sizeof` operator). The binary representation of an object of `std::vector<int>` does not contain any vector elements*. It typically just contains a pointer to the dynamically-allocated storage on the heap, where the elements are stored. (*) This would be in theory possible with _small buffer optimization_ technique, but this is not allowed for `std::vector`. There are other vector implementations that implement it (such as `boost::container::small_vector`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `vector<foo>` consists of two parts: a fixed-size block consisting of a pointer and a count of elements, and a variable-sized block which the pointer points to. When you create a new `vector<foo>`, it contains no `foo`s; the count of elements is zero, and the pointer (depending on implementation) is likely null. When you destroy the vector (which happens when you delete `vu`), it frees the variable-sized block.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this code safe?

Yes.

> If so, how does c++ know how much memory to allocate ...

It's the vector's responsibility to know about and manage its own storage *specifically* so you don't have to.

This is the entire point of encapsulation. All *you* have to do is make sure that the vector itself gets created and destroyed properly (which is all fine in the code as shown).